# The import org.mybatis.dynamic cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I want to try the example of dynamic update statement on this tutorial link : http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/update.html. I saw that it needs the import org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.update.render.UpdateStatementProvider; , So i've searched for dependency in the maven central and added below dependency on my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.dynamic-sql/mybatis-dynamic-sql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Already tried mvn clean install -U on maven build but still The import org.mybatis.dynamic cannot be resolved error always shows. Where can i have the correct maven dependency for this. Or you can suggest me other dynamic update statement approach on mybatis using xml mapper.

Comment: `mybatis-dynamic-sql` seems to be the correct jar. It has a class called `org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.update.render.UpdateStatementProvider`. Is everything right with your project setup?

Comment: You have a new version of the library  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.dynamic-sql/mybatis-dynamic-sql/1.1.0

Comment: I have a new problem how can i map the column name on the .set() method. It says: Cannot invoke set(String) on the primitive type void

Comment: @Malt yeah i think i already fix it, i have multiple imports on my maven i just select the suggested fix project setup by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I also added the newest version of it and everything worked as expected. I had the problem, that mybatis-spring-boot-starter did not include mybatis-dynamic-sql.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```